# Google Cloud Load Balancer - 502 - Unmanaged instance group failing health checks

Tags: nginx, ssl, redhat, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I currently have an HTTPS Load Balancer setup operating with a 443 Frontend, Backend and Health Check that serves a single host nginx instance.

When navigating directly to the host via browser the page loads correctly with valid SSL certs.

When trying to access the site through the load balancer IP, I receive a 502 - Server error message. I check the Google logs and I notice "failed_to_pick_backend" errors at the load balancer. I also notice that it failing health checks.

Some digging around leads me to these two links: https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/07/Debugging-Health-Checks-in-Load-Balancing-on-Google-Compute-Engine.html

https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/1195

Issue #1 - Not sure if google-address-manager is running on the server (RHEL 7). I do not see an entry for the HTTPS load balancer IP in the routes. The Google SDK is installed. This is a Google-provided image and if I update the IP address in the console, it also gets updated on the host. How do I check if google-address-manager is running on RHEL7?

```
[root@server]# ip route ls table local type local scope host
10.212.2.40 dev eth0 proto kernel src 10.212.2.40
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel src 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 dev lo proto kernel src 127.0.0.1
```

Output of all google services

```
[root@server]# systemctl list-unit-files
google-accounts-daemon.service                enabled
google-clock-skew-daemon.service              enabled
google-instance-setup.service                 enabled
google-ip-forwarding-daemon.service           enabled
google-network-setup.service                  enabled
google-shutdown-scripts.service               enabled
google-startup-scripts.service                enabled
```

Issue #2: Not receiving a 200 OK response. The certificate is valid and the same on both the LB and server. When running curl against the app server I receive this response.

```
root@server.com  curl -I https://app-server.com
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

[Troubleshoot the health checks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks), and once they're up and running the odds are good that the rest of the issues will vanish (especially since your backend is returning content).